# Convert a HTML Table with rowspans to DataTable C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to convert a Html Table to DataTable in C#. I used HtmlAgilityPack but it does not convert it well because of rowspans.
The code I am currently using is:

```
      private static DataTable convertHtmlTableToDataTable()
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string urlContent = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.com");

        string tableCode = getTableCode(urlContent);

        string htmlCode = tableCode.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
        var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/th");
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (HtmlNode header in headers)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(header.InnerText);
        }
        foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]"))
        {
            table.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
        }
        return table;
    }
```

And this is a part of Html Table:

```
        <table class="tabel" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <caption style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:20px;">SEMGRP</caption>
    <tr>
        <th class="celula" >Ora</th>
        <th  class="latime_celula celula">Luni</th>
        <th  class="latime_celula celula">Marti</th>
        <th  class="latime_celula celula">Miercuri</th>
        <th  class="latime_celula celula">Joi</th>
        <th  class="latime_celula celula">Vineri</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celula" nowrap="nowrap">8-9</td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">   
                                            Curs    
                                            <br />
                                            <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=287&amp;tip=p">Prof</a> 
                                            <br />
                                            <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=9&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                                            Curs    
                                            <br />
                                            <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=287&amp;tip=p">Prof</a> 
                                            <br />
                                            <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=12&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>  
                                            <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
                                        Curs
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=293&amp;tip=p">Prof</a>
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=9&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>
                                        <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celula" nowrap="nowrap">9-10</td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celula" nowrap="nowrap">10-11</td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">   Curs
                                        <br /><a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=303&amp;tip=p">Prof</a>
                                        <br /><a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=9&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>
                                        <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">   Curs
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=331&amp;tip=p">Prof</a>
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=14&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>  
                                        <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">   Curs
                                        <br /><a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=330&amp;tip=p">Prof</a>   
                                        <br /><a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=9&amp;tip=s">Sala</a> 
                                        <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="celula" rowspan="2">
                                <table border="0" align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">   Curs
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=293&amp;tip=p">Prof</a>
                                        <br />
                                        <a class="link_celula" href="afis_n0.php?id_tip=10&amp;tip=s">Sala</a>  <br />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="celula" nowrap="nowrap">11-12</td>
        <td class="celula">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

I tried some solutions but I did not find any good...
Thanks for any help in advance.